# Spotfire calculated column equivalent in DAX Power BI

Tags: powerbi, concatenation, dax, calculated-columns, spotfire

Can any one help me here. I am trying to convert a calculated column in spotfire to power bi. But unable to find a dax equivalent for this.

1. Spotfire expression -

If((case when (UniqueConcatenate(Concatenate("'",[productgroup],"'"))over [customer]) ~= '${Product2}'
then [customer] end)

=

(case when (UniqueConcatenate(Concatenate("'",[productgroup],"'")) over [customer]) ~= '${Product1}'
then '' else [customer] end),[cutomer],NULL)

couldn't find a unique concatenate equivalent in power bi. Tried with concatenate(distinct) , but it returns an error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you describe in plain english what the expression does ?

Comment: in addition to what Jeremie L asks. It's not clear how many tables are involved. And names like 'Table Name'[column name]

Answer (score 0):

IF (
CALCULATE (
DISTINCTCOUNT ( TableName[productgroup] ),
FILTER ( ALL ( TableName[customer] ), TableName[customer] = EARLIER ( TableName[customer] ) )
)
= 1
&& CONCATENATEX ( VALUES ( TableName[productgroup] ), TableName[productgroup], ", " ) <> '${Product2}'
&& CONCATENATEX ( VALUES ( TableName[productgroup] ), TableName[productgroup], ", " ) <> '${Product1}',
TableName[customer],
BLANK ()
)